# Hooking custom actions when deleting cascadingly

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

A simple case. A user has many photos. When a user gets deleted, all of his/her photos should be deleted too (rule of cascades).

I want however to be able to execute some custom code right before every photo is deleted.

Unfortunately, when deleting users, all I am doing is call userDAO.deleteUser(userID), so no specific action is taken on photos (they are deleted by Hibernate itself)

Also, I don't really want the userDAO to have the knowledge that a user has photos, so this custom code should be inserted somewhere else.

I wish it were as simple as giving an OnDelete callback when I annote my entity classes, but I haven't seen any such specification in the Hibernate docs

Comment: @danny.lesnik yes. I forgot to mention it

Answer (score -1):

Then I Think you need to apply SPring AOP on the function which deletes user.

for example:

```
public void deleteUser(User user){
Session session = sessionFactory.getcurrentSection();
//delete the object

}
```

What you need to do is to apply `@Around` advice

```
 @Pointcut("execution(* com.vanilla.dao.*.*(..))")
    public void deleteUserMethods() { }

    @Around("deleteUserMethods()")
    public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
            Object output = pjp.proceed();
            ///perform any operations on an pjp and its parameters.
            return output;
    }
```

I recommend you to see this example:

http://veerasundar.com/blog/2010/01/spring-aop-example-profiling-method-execution-time-tutorial/

and Spring documentation will be also very helpful:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-schema

Comment: This is way over engineered for something that's already supported by JPA: lifecycle callback listeners, in this case @PreRemove: http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/PreRemove.html

Comment: Well yes, and technically your answer is better for such a setup, but you should use JPA in Hibernate, and not the old Hibernate Session/Session factory (it's recommanded by Hibernate itself). And while aspects have their usefulness, they are harder to implement/debug and should be avoided for such a simple task which has a cleaner, simpler solution.

Comment: No. This is SPring/Hibernate app. SessionFactory is bean and I'm getting session by sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(). Every hibernate transaction configured and managed by Spring AOP. so what is better to use, @preRemove or AOP?

Comment: Well you can use the AOP stuff, or you can make a separate listener class, inject the Hibernate sessionFactory in there so you have access to the current session, and then declare one of it;s methods as callable at the @PreRemove lifecycle event. You can attach such a listener to a bean class via class level config annotations

Comment: Agree but still can't realize why do you think that your proposal is easier then mine? -:) before answering this question I asked this man if he is using Spring. his answer was yes so I suggested to use AOP which is already out of the box in Spring :)

Comment: Hey, look, I really don't wanna be a trolling a**hole. Sorry I downvoted your answer, it's fine, and I actually tried to revert my vote but apparently SO won't let me. Truly honestly and no offence, I'd use my suggestion rather than yours, but that's just me. If the person asking the question finds your solution better, and mine worse, by all means, vote me down, and chose your answer as the correct one. No harm, no fawl?

Comment: @Andrei, not an issue :) You gave another view on this problem and this up to user to choose what is right.

Comment: I ended up writing a custom Hibernate listener, which I attached to the Hibernate SessionFactory. It works, but not very optimized, because it will be invoked on every DELETE call of every entity, and what I want is to intercept only the DELETE calls for the Photo entity. Using AOP, will I have more options to achieve this level of granularity?

Comment: Yes. You can Configure PointCut on specific methods which delete User and no Hibernate operation will be affected. and this is also transparent to Hibernate level.